# Behaviour of heights of prime ideals under restrictions.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a (possibly non-noetherian) domain, and $A \colon= R[[X_1,\cdots,X_n]]$ be a formal power series ring over $R$. Suppose that ${\frak P}$ is a prime ideal of $A$ such that the height of ${\frak P}$ is $k$ and that ${\frak P} \cap R = 0$.

Let us consider the subring $B \colon= R[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$ of $A$. Let us denote by ${\frak p}$ the intersection of ${\frak P}$ and $B$ in $A$. Thus, ${\frak p}$ is the prime ideal of $B$.

### Q. Is the height of ${\frak p}$ bigger than or equal to $k$?

Comment: One can replace R by its field of fractions. Now A is B-flat, so Going Down theorem holds.

Comment: Why after tensoring the fractional field $K$ of $R$ can we prove the flatness of it over $K[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$?

Comment: Since it is the completion.